# Logo is indicating base instead my custom theme?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am implementing my custom theme in magento. All required settings are done in admin panel and on FTP all structures are fine, but when I inspect logo, its indicating base theme src URL.

Comment: only logo is coming from base theme or css and js files also?

Comment: yes if i try to include js/css in local.xml those were also pointing to base theme

Comment: check this configuration: http://prntscr.com/ca7eay

Comment: my package is karte->default, what should i need to specify there?

Comment: provide snap for config->General>design

Comment: here is snapshot http://prntscr.com/ca7miq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your snap your theme folder structure should be like this:

```
app\design\frontend\karte\karte
```

if its `app\design\frontend\karte\default`

than configure it like this: 
[image]

Notes:

1. Flush magento cache and check for theme.
2. Skin files should be there in `skin\frontend\karte\default`

[image]

Comment: not working see this screen shot http://prntscr.com/ca7pt6

Comment: have you added skin files in their respective folder?

Comment: skin>frontend>karte>default>css,js,images

Comment: yes put logo in images folder

Comment: yes thanks my mistake , logo is already in skin folder just need to update that in admin panel from gif to png. thanks

Comment: yes welcome !!!